# C# only displays 1 string from my array

Tags: c#

I'm currently programming something and it dont works so good.

I have splitted my string all fine but now the problem is i want display all nicknames from the splitted array, it only display 1 from all.

Code:

```
string content = "nickname:steve ID:01 weapon:false nickname:peter ID:02 weapon:false nickname:john ID:03 weapon:true"
var split = content.split(' ');
Console.WriteLine(split);
```

Output:

```
nickname:steve
ID:01
weapon:false
nickname:peter
ID:02
weapon:false
nickname:john
ID:03
weapon:true
```

No I have tryed with index:

```
   Console.WriteLine(split[0]);
```

Output:

```
nickname:steve
```

But I want this output:

```
nickname:steve
nickname:peter
nickname:john
```

Comment: FYI you're only selecting the first position of your array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just filter the not required lines with Linq `Where()`

```
string content = "nickname:steve ID:01 weapon:false nickname:peter ID:02 weapon:false nickname:john ID:03 weapon:true";
content.Split().Where(x => x.StartsWith("nickname")).ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use regex

```
var input = "nickname:steve ID:01 weapon:false nickname:peter ID:02 weapon:false nickname:john ID:03 weapon:true";
var matches = Regex.Matches(input,@"nickname:\w*");
foreach(Match match in matches)
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
```

**Output**

```
nickname:steve
nickname:peter
nickname:john
```

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OXwKIa)

Answer (score 0):

Only elements 0,3,6 etc have the values you want, so you could do this

```
for(var i=0;i<split.Length;i+=3)
    Console.WriteLine(split[i])
```

You could also generate the range, and use it to select the items

```
var result = Enumerable.Range(0,split.length-1).Where((i%3) == 0).Select(i => split[i])
Console.WriteLine(String.Join("\r\n",result));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use that

```
string content = "nickname:steve ID:01 weapon:false nickname:peter ID:02 weapon:false nickname:john ID:03 weapon:true";
content.Replace("nickname:", "").Split(' ').ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```